# Find duplicate strings in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find all rows in my table where the strings of a specific field are duplicates in two or more places.

Can that be done in a MySQL statment?

**EDIT**

I need to get every row not just a count of how many duplicates there are. I want to be able to edit the fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `YourTable`
WHERE `YourColumn` IN (
    SELECT `YourColumn`
    FROM `YourTable`
    GROUP BY `YourColumn`
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Your query freezes my PHPmyadmin. Maybe it is because i have +7000 rows

Comment: That's odd. Works fine for me on large tables. Maybe some other query is causing locking issues?

Comment: Hmmm... I will try to check out any problems in my setup.

Comment: It is definetly my setup. Other tables works properly using this query.

Comment: @RichardFawcett It worked for selected column ! So, thanks for your contribution. Any suggestions for string of row of selected column?

Comment: Hey @ersks, I'm not sure what you mean by "string of row of selected column".  Can you clarify please?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

```
SELECT mycolumn, count(*) FROM mytable
group by mycolumn
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I need to have every row shown. Not only the count. I want to be able to edit the row.

Comment: @Cudos you can add other fields to SELECT so you can fetch whatever field you need. For example:

  SELECT id, field1, field2, mycolumn, count(\*) FROM mytable
  group by mycolumn
  having count(*) > 1