# mysql query: count by column where column > number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find duplicate strings in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407161/find-duplicate-strings-in-database)

im querying a mysql database with php.

I need to know what names are repeated over 375 in the table (it has 375 rows). The table contains 3 columns: id, name, category.

Here is my php code, however it counts with php, and i want it to be made with mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_likes"; 
//echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// craete arrays
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    set_time_limit(0);
    $like[$row['name']]=$like[$row['name']]+1;
    if($like[$row['name']]==375) $likes375 ++; 

}
```

If someone could help me ill appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if my answer isn't helpful -- I don't clearly understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, count(*) likes 
FROM user_likes 
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 375
```

Comment: when using this appreach i receive: Lost connection to MySQL server during quer.... the db has over 20 million rows, so probably it takes too long and the connection is closed

Comment: Try making a view on mysql from that select statement and querying the view from the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some SQL to count the number of likes per name.

```
SELECT name, count(*) likes FROM user_likes GROUP BY name;
```

Here is some SQL to filter for names that have more than 375 likes

```
SELECT i.name, i.likes
FROM ( SELECT name, count(*) likes FROM user_likes GROUP BY name) i
WHERE i.likes > 375
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to find duplicated names:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM user_likes GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) = 375"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$names = array();    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $names[] = $row['name'];
}

print_r($names);
```

Comment: thats not actually what im trying to achieve... i want to display only the names that are repeated 375 times

Comment: @DanStern That's the same, check my updated answer, it is even easier.

Comment: @DanStern If you want 375 times and more, then change `=` to `>=`

Comment: thats true! howver im having another problem related to the same. when using this appreach i receive: Lost connection to MySQL server during query.... the db has over 20 million rows, so probably it takes too long and the connection is closed